# Adding a chart dynamicaly on a pane and fitting to its parent

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am adding a chart in javafx 8 dynamicaly on a pane. The chart is added normally but it won't fit the parent. This is the code:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPaneSessionChartTab" prefHeight="534.0" prefWidth="951.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.nokia.avalanche.client.controller.SessionChartTabController">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="-3.0" prefHeight="534.0" prefWidth="951.0">
        <children>
            <Pane fx:id="chartPane" prefHeight="393.0" prefWidth="951.0" />
            <TableView fx:id="tableViewStatisticsOverview" prefHeight="92.0" prefWidth="791.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="tableColumnStatisticName" prefWidth="558.9999694824219" text="Mesaurement Name" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="tableColumnShowSeries" minWidth="3.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="Show" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="328.0" text="Action" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
            <HBox nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="791.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="btnSaveChart" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnSaveChartClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="115.0" text="Save Chart">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="btnDeleteChart" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnDeleteChartClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="115.0" text="Delete Chart" />
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I am getting my pane on my java source code and trying adding my chart. But The chart doesn't expand to catch the full area of the pane. Is it possible to call a method like fit to parent (scene builder has it as an option in context menu of each control).

Comment: Use other type of pane: StackPane,VBox,HBox etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [HBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) instead of a pane. Give it the attribute VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS".
Then create your chart, call [setFillHeight(true)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setFillHeight-boolean-) on it, and insert it in your HBox.

*(By giving "VBox.vgrow ALWAYS" to the HBox, you're asking it to fill the VBox height. HBox is always as wide as possible. Child component of HBox always fill the width available. And HBox looks for child component's FillHeight property to determine if it should fill its own height. Job done!)*

EDIT - By the way, I'd recommend not "hard-coding" your width/height in the FXML. Except in very few cases, it's always better to have an "extensible" layout. Additionally, using an AnchorPane with only one child is pointless. May I recommend you to have a look at this guide: [Working With Layouts in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm)